# Python API using 'Requests' is connecting to URL but producing error when retrieving data

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am running the following Python script that is taken from a tutorial video.  This works on the video but when I copy the script it appears to connect to the API but then errors when returning the content.  This is the short script...

```
import requests
import json

baseurl = 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup'
parameters = {'UPC': '0885909950805'}
response = requests.get(baseurl, params=parameters)
print(response.url)

content = response.content
info = json.loads(content)
print(type(info))
print(info)
```

The output is as below :

```
https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?UPC=0885909950805

<class 'dict'>

{'code': 'INVALID_QUERY', 'message': 'Missing upc or invalid JSON format.'}
```

Could someone please explain what is causing the error message.

Many thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter "upc" should be in lower case.
Using:

```
parameters = {'upc': '0885909950805'}
```

gives the following url: https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=0885909950805
which gets a valid response.